# Windows 10 Insider Preview says my PIN is incorrect

Tags: insider-preview, windows-10-mobile

I just installed Insider Preview. System needs PIN to be entered. I entered my PIN and phone refused it as incorrect. PIN is 100% correct. I had document related to my SIM, where I have PIN, PUKK, PIN2, PUKK2. Phone refuses all of them. There is no option to skip this step and use phone without sim. I have only Emergency call here. 
When I physically remove sim from the phone. I cannot do anything but Emergency call.

Does anyone had problem like this? Did you solve it?

Thanks in regard for any hint

Comment: What phone do you have? Are you sure it's asking for the SIM card's PIN, and not the phone's? If it's the SIM PIN, then **as a last resort** you could enter it incorrectly 3 times, which will lock the SIM, then use the PUK code to unlock and enter a new PIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the phone won't let you past the PIN screen, it is not the SIM PIN but the phone pin that is required. You probably set this up before updating to the preview.

If you can't remember it you have to do a hard reset.

Comment: well, I din't expect password to be called PIN... but thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure it's your Phone PIN that is now allowing you to unlock your phone, the only step I can look forward is hard resetting your phone.

Make sure your phone is charged enough before you proceed. 
Disconnect your phone and switch it off.  Press volume down and camera button at the same time along with power button. That means, you have to press Volume Down + Camera button + Power key at the same time. Once your phone vibrates, release the power button but not the other two. You phone will reboot to factory settings. No more passwords.

Warning: You will loose all your Phone's data in the process.

Source: [How to reset Windows Phone password](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2015/12/how-to-reset-windows-phone-password.html)