# win 10 no butons to enter pin after win 10 upgrade

Tags: insider-preview

After upgrade my phone to win 10 Sim PIN shown but after acceptance of SIM PIN no digits at screen to enter pin code to unlock phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12232/106

Comment: Can you add a photo of what your screen looks like? Sounds like you'll need to do a hard reset.

Comment: same problem
and phone doesn't detect my sim card tooo each update contains a new problem instead of improvements i've been locked up from my phone